# Disable waring 'Type of property circularly references itself in mapped type' or workaround

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, jsdoc

how i can disable this kind of error in my whole project or maybe a work around ?

> Type of property 'UID' circularly references itself in mapped type
> 'Partial'.ts(2615)

[image]

So here the issue with js and vscode.
If i say data type is `/** @param {A} [data] */`
the error are from `new A({})` instance, i need fully fill the partial object or i get linter error !

[image]

if i say data type is a partial obj `/** @param {Partial<A>} [data] */`, now `new A({})` work fine, but i get linter error to constructor !

[image]

And if i say `/** @param {A|Partial<A>} [data] */` , no more error ! but all props became undefined (any) and lost types !!!
Vscode IntelliSense seem little bit lost in this case. !

[image]

---

here a sample code, how i can say Data is a partial objet, but if nothing, default are set !!!!

**test case:** `/** @param {A} [data]*/`  -  `/** @param {Partial<A>} [data] */` - `/** @param { A | Partial<A>} [data] */`

```js
export class A {
    /** @param {Partial<A>} [data] */ // how say is partial and also default ? 
    constructor(data) {
        /** uid global du data */
        this.UID = data.UID || 'noUID';
        this.prop = data.prop || {};
    }
    get VIEW() {
        return this.constructor.name;
    }
}

const a = new A ({UID:'g42t'})
```

Thanks for any help or suggest,

I would like an effective solution which allows to have a good workflow, without repetitions

i also open issue here, if is a bug ?
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108062

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok solved , intellisense work fine with this kind of structure. thanks all.

Little bit ugly for eye, but it fine and accesible to all parent extends constructors.

```js
export class A {

    /**@readonly - UID ...desc */
    UID = UTILITY.create_UID();
    /**@readonly - UID2 ...desc */
    UID2 = '';
    /** @param {Partial<Omit<A, 'UID'>>} [data] */
    constructor(data,{UID2}=data) {
        this.UID2 = UID2 || 'perform default thing...';
    }
}

const a = new A ({UID2:'sada'}); // intellisence will not suggest UID here :)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on what this is meant to solve!!,  were has the VIEW gone?.  Why do we now have UID2.  this code doesn't look like the original.  TS complains for me :(

Comment: @Keith I agree and I am sorry if I misplaced my problem, if I would have copied the original code people would be complaining about reducing the code :) , and unfortunately it are the simplest version of my structure I can provide. And sorry for the `VIEW` 
it has nothing to do there,  it was a temporary fix, because I am currently converting all my project to React and a Store proxi. So there is a bit of weird code.
In fact, using some hack mixed with public,private structure work fine!  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you never tagged this Typescript too.  :)

But a partial of a class here doesn't really make much sense, normally types source of truth is some sort of interface / type, inferred types of course are only inferred from some sort off concrete type.   Here you haven't given your class any concrete types, so Typescript will try to infer and will fail for obvious reasons, but even if it didn't it's not going to be very useful, eg. it's going to have a `readonly VIEW()` not something I think your after, do you really want to to be able to send an optional `readonly View()`??.

So the simple solution, just give data it's type your expecting.

eg.

```
export class A {
    /** @param {{UID?:string, prop?:object}} [data] */ 
    constructor(data) {
        /** uid global du data */
        this.UID = data.UID || 'noUID';
        this.prop = data.prop || {};
    }
    get VIEW() {
        return this.constructor.name;
    }
}

const a = new A ({UID:'g42t'})
```

Comment: Hum, that's kind of what I wanted to avoid doing!, types myself all intellisenses by hand in jsdoc.  Is bad for the (workflow) and need repeat code.

But i found a miracle solution where all work almost automatically. !

`/** @param {Partial<Omit<A, 'UID'>>} [data] */`  and than add default to public space, and tag `/**@readonly - UID  */`  if needed!.


Everything seem work fine now ! thanks for your time.

Comment: i cant tag typescript because is max 5 tags, so sorry i cant fix this.

Comment: @jon  I would have dropped types, and put typescript in.  I think you would have had more responses from the typescript community than just me.